# Can I say "feeding the server with data by the bus riders"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I want to write something about Android app for bus tracking system based on Crowdsourcing. So can I use feeding like this? "Feeding the server with data by the bus riders"

Comment: I recommend this question be migrated to [ELL.SE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say "Feeding the server with data from the bus riders by the bus riders themselves"

Comment: Something like "Feeding the server with bus rider data, provided by the riders themselves" might be more natural.